# Android ProgressDialog returned null

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I am trying to make a progress Dialog when catching data using JSON.
but it always returned a null. Here is  the code :

```
class NetWork extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayAdapter<?>> {

        private ProgressDialog pd;

        public void Network() {
            try {
                ServiceStations service = new ServiceStations();
                service.load(WorkshopActivity.this.getApplicationContext());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // do nothing
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // do nothing
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            pd = new ProgressDialog(WorkshopActivity.this);
            pd.setMessage("Load");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        }

        @Override
        public ArrayAdapter<?> doInBackground(Void... params) {


            @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
            final ArrayAdapter<?> areaAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(
                    WorkshopActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    ServiceStations.getAreaList());

            return areaAdapter;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            try {
                pd.show(); // this returns null
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(ArrayAdapter<?> areaAdapter) {
            /*
             * if (dialog.isShowing()) { dialog.dismiss(); }
             */
            list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listWorkshopCity);
            list.setAdapter(areaAdapter);
            adapter = areaAdapter;
        }

    }
```

here is the stacktrace :

```
07-15 04:34:15.006: W/System.err(3393): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-15 04:34:15.006: W/System.err(3393):     at com.jatismobile.iklaim.activities.WorkshopActivity$NetWork.onPreExecute(WorkshopActivity.java:74)
07-15 04:34:15.026: W/System.err(3393):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
07-15 04:34:15.026: W/System.err(3393):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
07-15 04:34:15.036: W/System.err(3393):     at com.jatismobile.iklaim.activities.WorkshopActivity.onCreate(WorkshopActivity.java:102)
```

I've been trying to search the internet, yet I have found the solution to this
Any help will be apreciated. thanks..

Comment: are you creating an instance of your asynctask using Network Constructor only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this

```
 public void Network()
```

Constructor does not have a return type

It should be

```
 public Network()
 {
      // rest of the code
 }
```

You initialize your progressdialog in a method which is not called. You do not call method Network any where in your class. Hence `NullPointerException`

Comment: @user1722156 also note that all your network realted operation should be done in `doInbackGround`.If `ServiceStations` does network realed operation move it inside `doInbackground`. Also `service.load(WorkshopActivity.this)`. You already have the activity context.